# get in json encode 1st array as index and from the 2nd value of that indexs

Tags: php, json, csv

```
[
   {
        Account_type: "Account Type",
        Account_number: "Account Number",
        Transaction_date: "Transaction Date",
        Description_1: "Description 1",
        Description_2: "Description 2",
        currency: "Currency",
        amount: "Amount"
   },
   {
        Account_type: "Savings",
        Account_number: "05456-7087489",
        Transaction_date: "4/2/2015",
        Description_1: "CREDIT TRANSACTION",
        Description_2: "2394252 DEP@CR",
        currency: "BSD",
        amount: "528.3"
    },
    {
        Account_type: "Savings",
        Account_number: "05456-7087489",
        Transaction_date: "4/7/2015",
        Description_1: "RBC ATM WDL",
        Description_2: "# 326353908",
        currency: "BSD",
        amount: "-200"
   },
   {
        Account_type: "Savings",
        Account_number: "05456-7087489",
        Transaction_date: "4/15/2015",
        Description_1: "RBC ATM WDL",
        Description_2: "# 905509738",
        currency: "BSD",
        amount: "-150"
    }
]
```

Comment: what you want from us?

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.